# Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: Don't know how to iterate over supplied "items" in &lt;forEach&gt;

Tags: jsp, servlets, foreach

I am using the following code,

The xxx - is the `LinkedHashMap`

The yyy - is the `HashMap`

When I iterate the `yyy`, the following error occurred. Can you please anypone explain about this **error** and *what is the solution for this*.

```
<c:forEach var="aaa" items="${xxx}">
<c:set var="yyy" value="${projects.key}"/>
<c:forEach var="test" items="${yyy}">                                                                 
</c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: what are you trying to do ? Are you trying to iterate the map using jstl ?

Comment: @SanKrish ya, exactly.

Answer (score 0):

To iterate your `LinkedHashMap` xxx, you need iterate its `key` and `value`

```
  <c:forEach var="row" items="${xxx}"> 
               ${row.key}
               ${row.value}            
         </c:forEach>      
   </c:forEach>
```

you neednt assign it to the variable to iterate its values as `jstl` provides you the way